# Suggestions for $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\int_x^y \frac{\arctan{(t^3)}}{x+y} dt\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve this limit over "its natural domain": $\Bbb R^2 \cap (x+y \neq 0)$, I suppose.
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\int_x^y \frac{\arctan{(t^3)}}{x+y} dt\
$$

=========
My attempt:
1. $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,mx) \to 0$ with $(m \neq -1)$
2. $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,x^2) \to 0$

I tried to evaluate the limt "near" the line $(-y,y)$ where there could be some problems:
3. $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(-y\pm y^2,y) \to 0$ (if anybody wants to see steps ask me and I'll edit the post)

So I was thinking the limits could be $0$. I also tried to graph the function:
[image]

and I can't see any "strange curve" which I can exploit to disprove my conjecture.

So I tried to make such an estimation:
* $ |f(x,y| \le g(x,y) $
* $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} g(x,y) \to 0$

For first I did: $$
\left|\int_x^y \frac{\arctan{(t^3)}}{x+y} dt\ \right| \le \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{|y-x|}{|x+y|}
$$
But the last limit doesn't exist.

Then I tried the change of variables: $|x|=u^2$, $|y|=v^2$, separating the various cases; but I fail when I evaluate the cases $(x>0, y<0)$ and $(x<0, y>0)$. For example, the firts: $$
\left|\int_{u^2}^{-v^2} \frac{\arctan{(t^3)}}{u^2-v^2} dt\ \right| \le -\int_{u^2}^{-v^2} \left|\frac{\arctan{(t^3)}}{u^2-v^2}\right| dt\ \le -\frac{1}{|u^2-v^2|} \int_{u^2}^{-v^2} \left|t^3 \right| dt\ \le \frac{u^8+v^8}{|u^2-v^2|}
$$
Again, I think the last limit doesn't exist.

=========
Has anybody some hints to solve the limit?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to assume $x,y > 0$, otherwise if $x=-y$ it is infinite. With that assumption, since the derivative of arctan is 1 at 0, you can bound $arctan(t^3)$ by a constant times $t^3$, then just do the integration, and go from there.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but he did do that in the 3rd step of the last integral attempt?

Comment: Yes, but he had $x<0<y$, which is a case I think you have to exclude.

Comment: @Greg I don't think I can exclude other cases except for $x>0, y>0$; infact it is the second question of exercise. I have at least to show the limit doesn't exist at all..

Comment: Wait, I was wrong, if $x=-y$ then you get $0/0$, I overlooked the fact that the integral is $0$. But what about the following argument? The power series of $arctan(t^3)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^{6n+3}}{2n}$. Integrate term by term to get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(y^{6n+4}-x^{6n+4})}{2n(6n+4)(x+y)}$. Then you can factor $(y^{6n+4}-x^{6n+4})$ and cancel the $x+y$ in the denominator. Then you obtain $(x-y)(y^{6n+2} + y^6 x^2 + ... + x^{6n+2})$, and the modulus is $\leq |x-y| (3n+2) \max(|x|,|y|)^{6n+2}$. I think this limit should be $0$, no?

Comment: At the end, I found another simpler solution. But, I really can't understand how you have factorized the numerator. Also, can you handle infinite sum into limits?

Comment: I used $x^{2m}-y^{2m} = (x^2-y^2)(x^{2m-2} + x^{2m-4} y^2 + .. + x^2 y^{2m-4} + y^{2m-2})$. If you multiply it out, the sum telescopes. You can break it up into an infinite sum here and integrate termwise because the sum converges rapidly enough (faster than geometic). There are some details, yes, but it's legit. Also for what I did I was holding $x,y$ fixed, then you get that bound. Then you let $x,y \to 0$ and take the limit.